# Need help to get variable in mfc dialog class

Tags: class, visual-c++, object, mfc

please, I've spent all day trying to figure this out but can't. I have a class (artist1) created from a dialog box with some edit boxes. I want to get the data typed in the edit boxes and save them to variables i made public in the class. But don't know why it doesn't work. PS am new to mfc programming. Thanks
here is my artist class

```
void artist1::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    //artist1 AA=*art1; 

    CEdit* pEdit1 = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1); 
    pEdit1->GetWindowText(Name1);
    nn=new CString;
    *nn=Name1;
    CEdit* pEdit2 = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2); 
    pEdit2->GetWindowText(Age1);
    n2=new CString;
    *n2=Age1;
    CEdit* pEdit3 = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3); 
    pEdit3->GetWindowText(Nationality1);
    n3=new CString;
    *n3=Nationality1;
    CEdit* pEdit4 = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT4); 
    pEdit4->GetWindowText(Group1);
    n4=new CString;
    *n4=Group1;
    CEdit* pEdit5 = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT5); 
    pEdit5->GetWindowText(num_of_albums1);
    n5=new CString;
    *n5=num_of_albums1;
    SH(Name1,Age1,Nationality1,Group1,num_of_albums1);
    art1=this;
//  memcpy(art1,this,sizeof(this));

    //Name_box.SetWindowText(g);
    //AfxMessageBox( Age );
    //AfxMessageBox( Nationality );
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

}

/*bool artist1::SH()
{
    if(NoShow==false)return true;
    else return false;
}*/
void artist1::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    //Cooplab1View vm;
    NoShow=false;
    nvalidateRect(NULL,NULL);
    EndDialog(IDD_FORMVIEW);

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

and here is the class artist header

```
class artist1 : public CDialogEx
{
    //DECLARE_DYNAMIC(artist1)

public:
    artist1(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~artist1();
    bool NoShow;
    bool *address;

    CString Albums[5];

    void OnInsertArtist(artist1 &at);
// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_FORMVIEW };
private:
    CString Nm;
    CString Ag;
    CString Nation;
    CString group;
    CString No_of_A;
    CString *nnn;

public:
    // artist1* GetTreeObj();
    //virtual CString ShowDetails(CDC* pDC);
    void SH(CString a,CString b,CString c,CString d,CString e)
{
    Name=a;
    Age=b;
    Nationality=c;
    Group=d;
    num_of_albums=e;
}

protected:
    CString Name,Age,Nationality,Group,num_of_albums;
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    CString Name1,Age1,Nationality1,Group1,num_of_albums1;
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
    virtual CString ShowDetails(CDC* pDC,artist1 & at1);

    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton2();
};
```

and i call the class from the CView class cpp file

```
void Cooplab1View::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    artist1 art;
    artist1 A1;
    Cooplab1Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    //ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    //if (!pDoc)
    //  return;



    if (noShow)
    {
        art.OnInsertArtist(art);
        //art.OnBnClickedButton1();
        //art=&obj;
    //  art.GetTreeObj();
        art.ShowDetails(pDC,art);
    }

    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    // TODO: add draw code for native data here
}


void Cooplab1View::OnInsertArtist1()
{
    noShow=true;
    InvalidateRect(NULL,NULL);
    //UpdateWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I declared some global variables, assigned the values inputted in the edit boxes to them in OnBnClickedButton1() using GetDlgItemText then in OnBnClickedButton2() i assigned the  global variables to the variables in my class ie Name, Age etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create variables (right click->Add variables in vs2010) matching your "edit boxes" and check their values.
   Don't do "GetDlgItem" and not GetWindowText.
2. You should add`UpdateData(TRUE)` at the first line of `OnBnClickedButton1`
3. Good Luck !

Comment: have done that. but when i click button 2 so as to display it, all the entries turn to NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your class is quite messy, but if you just want to extract user entry text from the dialog items, it is actually quite simple.

```
void artist1::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // Since variables Name,Age,Nationality,Group,num_of_albums are all CString items
    // declare as member variables in the class, 
    // you can just retrieve user entry from the dialog directly into them
    // without calling the "SH(Name1,Age1,Nationality1,Group1,num_of_albums1);"
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, Name);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, Age);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT3, Nationality);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT4, Group);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT5, num_of_albums);
}
```

Comment: have done that. but when i click button 2 so as to display it, all the entries turn to NULL

Comment: my problem is how to get the variables i stored so that another class can inherit them

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering a value to the edit control, you should call updatedata( FALSE ). If you want to store the value into a variable then call updatedata(TRUE). That's it.